# How to break an autohotkey loop when app closes

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey to enter some keystrokes repeatedly into an old script. I don't know beforehand how long it will go on, so I have this script:

```
#NoEnv
^m::

Loop 
{
if (BreakLoop = 1)
  break 
  SEND, 3
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  sleep, 100
}

Esc::
BreakLoop = 1
return
```

And I wait for it to finish, and enter escape when it finishes (the sleep timer is there so I can actually escape).

As soon as the script is finished the window closes, and I'd like to use that event to break the autohotkey loop, but haven't figured out how as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinActive or WinExist to check for the window closing.  You can also use a while statement to combine the conditional break statements instead of needing a separate if/break.  I would also make sure and initialize the BreakLoop variable in case you run the script multiple times without totally restarting it.

```
#NoEnv
^m::
setTitleMatchMode, 2               ; inexact title match
myID := WinExist(myWinTitle:="A")  ; put WinSpy title details here
BreakLoop = 0
While !BreakLoop and WinActive("ahk_id" myID)
{
  SEND, 3
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  SEND, {Enter}
  sleep, 100
}

Esc::
BreakLoop = 1
return
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the code, I figured using the [active window](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) would be what I wanted, but then the script didn't start. Am I missing something? I'd like to run the script until the active window closes, I used the sample code above and replaced "title ahk_exe my.exe" with "A". Thanks for looking into this with me :).

Comment: Remove the not statement in front of WinActive... logic error.  You want the loop to run while the window is active. However, you cannot use A for the window, unless you read the ID first. Otherwise the loop will always find an active window, it will just be a different window.

Comment: Updated the code block above to reflect changes noted my previous comment.  This will read the active window and check for that window until it is no longer active.